# In objective-c , how can an object return a different proxy object when itself is assigned as a delegate it implements

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c-runtime, nsinvocation

I have an object which implements various protocols (like 10 different ones).

For example

```
@interface MyClass <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchDisplayDelegate,...>

@end

@implementation

/// a whole bunch of methods for the delegates
@end
```

In order to "clean" things up in this class - I have created helper classes which encapsulates the logic pertaining to those delegates.

so now the new refactored class looks something like

```
// public interface which looks the same
@interface MyClass <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchDisplayDelegate,...>


@end

// private interface

@interface MyClass ()

// a bunch of objects which implement those methods
@property (nonatomic,strong) MyUITableviewDelegate *tableViewDelegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) MyUITableviewDataSource *tableViewDelegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) MySearchDisplayDelegate *searchDisplayDelegate;
// another bunch of objects which answer to the delegates
@end

@implementation
// all the delegate methods were moved out of here to the class which implements the method

@end
```

Now when an object of "`MyClass`" is assigned as a delegate - it should return the runtime object which "answers" to those delegates (for instance if "`MyClass`" object is assigned as a `UITableViewDelegate` - the `MyUITableviewDelegate` should be assigned.

How can this be done?
Must I override the `forwardInvocation` in the "`MyClass`" object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement [`forwardingTargetForSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector:)

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ([self.tableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        return self.tableViewDelegate;
    }
    // etc

    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}
```